# How to Group Rows based on some column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a data in a table as the following. This is just a sample data with only 1 AdmissionNo, real data may have hundreds of them with their own sets. So I want to group the rows based on AdmissionNo and WardCode, means top 13 rows with WardCode as 'KINT' should have grpValue as 1, then next two rows as 2, then 1 and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_H](
    [AdmissionNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [WardCode] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [AdmissionDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [DischargeDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-06-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-06-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-06 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-07 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-08 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KINT', CAST(N'2016-06-29 01:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-12 03:38:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-11 17:44:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-12 03:38:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KEHH', CAST(N'2016-07-12 03:38:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-14 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-17 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-18 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-19 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-21 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-22 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-23 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-24 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-25 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-07-31 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-01 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-02 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-03 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-05 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-06 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-07 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-08 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-09 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-10 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-11 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-12 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-13 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-14 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-15 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-16 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-17 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCAR', CAST(N'2016-07-12 13:25:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 10:59:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-18 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-19 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-20 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-21 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-22 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-23 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-18 13:35:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KICA - IC', CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:23:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-24 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KICA - IC', CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:23:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-25 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KICA - IC', CAST(N'2016-08-24 18:56:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:23:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:23:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-30 15:12:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-26 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-30 15:12:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-27 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-30 15:12:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-28 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-30 15:12:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-29 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl_H] ([AdmissionNo], [WardCode], [AdmissionDateTime], [DischargeDateTime], [date]) VALUES (N'0000001742', N'KCH2', CAST(N'2016-08-26 13:30:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-30 15:12:00.000' AS DateTime), CAST(N'2016-08-30 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime))
GO
```

This is how the table is looking:
[image: Table]

But the problem is that WardCode repeats again in later rows for the same AdmissinoNo. So how can I give those rows as different GroupValue, because when I try to group them, they group together even when any other WardCode is between them. The rows can be ordered based on AdmissionDateTime then DischargeDateTime.
First I added rownumber in the list by "ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY AdmissionNo,AdmissionDateTime,DischargeDateTime) as rownum", then made this query:

```
;WITH cte as (
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AdmissionNo,WardCode ORDER BY rownum) as rn,
       rownum - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AdmissionNo,WardCode ORDER BY rownum) as grp
FROM tbl_h
)    
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY grp) as new_Grp
FROM cte
```

But this is also grouping all the wardcodes with same name even if any other wardcode is between them.

Comment: I think your query works fine. Just add `order by rownum` to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the following query, thanks to Ajay Gupta:

```
;WITH cte as (
SELECT *,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AdmissionNo,WardCode ORDER BY rownum) as rn,
   rownum - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AdmissionNo,WardCode ORDER BY rownum) as 
grp
FROM tbl_h
)    
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY grp) as new_Grp
FROM cte
ORDER BY rownum
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
GROUP BY AdmissinoNo,WardCode
ORDER BY AdmissinoNo,WardCode
```

First Group it by AdmissinoNo and WardCode 
then Sort it by AdmissinoNo and WardCode

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if you look at the image, it will group 14,15 and 17, 18 and so on together, and thats what I dont want, because row 16 has different wardcode. so rows 14 and 15 should have different groupvalue and 17,18 and so on rows should have different groupvalue.